# Process Builder execute action on Opportunity stage change

Tags: opportunity, process-builder

So I know I'm screwing up this logic somehow but I'm trying to create a record based on opportunity stage change and whether or not LTD STD or Life is present in the string in the the Policy type field.

I activated the recursion assuming that this would be constantly looking for a change in the stage name that i specified but I'm now at a loss as this doesn't seem to be working.

[image]

Comment: I'm aware it isn't active in this picture

Comment: You say that you are looking for LTD/STD/Life in the "Policy Type" field, but looking at the picture the second field begins with a "G".  Is it possible you somehow chose the wrong field?

Comment: Wow I'm pretty sure you nailed it.  Must have been a mismatch of fields in my conversion process.  Thank you very much.

Comment: My motto for Salesforce Development: "It's always the little things"

Comment: @DougB - post as solution please

Comment: @cropredy Posted as a solution per your request

Answer (score 1):

You say that you are looking for LTD/STD/Life in the "Policy Type" field, but looking at the picture the second field begins with a "G". Is it possible you somehow chose the wrong field?

[image]